# What is the word used to describe the redundancy of using two synonyms to define one thing?

Tags: single-word-requests

- Incorrect: a baby lamb
- Correct?: 'a baby *sheep*', or just 'a lamb'

Is there even one word used to describe this duplication? Or would you just identify the mistake as "a redundant word"?

Comment: A pleonasm:  the use of more words than are required to express an idea.

Comment: In your particular example "baby" adds a little more than just emphasis. If a lamb is "a young sheep", a "baby lamb" is younger still -- not much more than a newborn (and presumably too cute to taste good -- yet).

Comment: See my tongue-in-cheek answer at https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/375945/idiom-for-a-speech-with-redundant-information/375949#375949

Comment: A doublet of synonyms is frequently used for emphasis.

Comment: It's called "English".

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the linguistic term is "[redundancy](http://grammarist.com/redundancies/)":

> In English usage, redundancy is usually defined as the use of two or more words that say the same thing, but we also use the term to refer to any expression in which a modifier’s meaning is contained in the word it modifies (e.g., early beginnings, merge together—many more are listed below). Think of redundancies as word overflows.
>
> This list is far from complete, and we’re developing it organically (i.e., adding redundancies as they come up in our work) rather than compiling the list by stealing from other online sources, which would be too easy. If you feel strongly that any redundancy should be added here, please comment.

Or, as Josh61 noted, [pleonasms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasm), specifically [semantic pleonasms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasm#Semantic_pleonasm):

> Pleonasm (/ˈpliːənæzəm/, from Greek πλεονασμός pleonasmos from πλέον pleon "more, too much") is the use of more words or parts of words than is necessary for clear expression: examples are black darkness, or burning fire. Such redundancy is, by traditional rhetorical criteria, a manifestation of [tautology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_%28rhetoric%29).
>
> Semantic pleonasm is a question more of style and usage than of grammar. Linguists usually call this redundancy to avoid confusion with syntactic pleonasm, a more important phenomenon for theoretical linguistics.

Answer (score 1):

Tautology!

The saying of the same thing twice over in different words, generally considered to be a fault of style (e.g. they arrived one after the other in succession ).
synonyms:   repetition, repetitiveness, repetitiousness, reiteration, redundancy, superfluity, periphrasis, iteration, duplication; More
a phrase or expression in which the same thing is said twice in different words.
plural noun: tautologies
LOGIC
a statement that is true by necessity or by virtue of its logical form.

Comment: 'Baby' and 'lamb' are different things. Had the writer said, 'an infant sheep, just a lamb' that would be a tautology. The two comments have expressed all that can be said and your answer has neither added anything more, nor is it correct. But do not be discouraged. Keep trying.

Comment: @NigelJ Thank you for this. That makes a lot of sense!