# "Brief moment" is what type of (incorrect) expression?

Tags: word-usage, etymology, grammaticality

"Bow down", "momentary pause"small little" and "brief moment" are what types of expression?  As an editor, I constantly have to correct this in people's writing.

Comment: _Small little_ is not an existing phrase at all, as far as I know. The others are all cases of redundancy, which is something that is completely commonplace in language. There’s nothing incorrect about it, though it may not always be the best option stylistically.

Comment: "A small, little knife"...I guess "small little" does get used, but probably should not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the word used to describe the redundancy of using two synonyms to define one thing?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/248760/what-is-the-word-used-to-describe-the-redundancy-of-using-two-synonyms-to-define)

Comment: These are not really redundancies, they are spotlights.  When the most important thing about a moment is how short it is, it makes sense to point to that feature; the "redundant" adjective is just how we do it.  Likewise, one can bow for any number of reasons, and bowing is always downward, but bowing "down" implies submission. Indeed, one can bow ironically, which is the very opposite of bowing "down,. Thus, "down," as a modifier of "bow," means socially downward more importantly than physically earthward. It's not so much a redundancy as a metaphor, as, indeed, is bowing itself.

Comment: A pause could be for only a moment or somewhat longer.

Answer (score 1):

They are redundant expressions and "bow down" is more akin to an idiom.  As far a tautologies are concerned; yeah, technically you can call them that.  Usually a tautology finds it's context in Formal Logic.  It is a redundant statement from which any conclusion derived is necessarily true.

Ex.  "I predict that tomorrow it will rain or it will not rain."

Something leads me to believe, no matter where you are, my prediction will be accurate.  That's generally how a tautology appears; otherwise, that's a fairly rare word in usage to call out something as redundant.

And as far as idioms are concerned, that is a tough one - they always appear as incorrect usage; and whether it might be acceptable as an idiom would be subject to the context of the writing (e.g., Non-fiction, Fiction, etc.) and the geographic context of the writing (some regional dialect is bound to overlook one "idiom" for its redundancy, where another regional dialect will call out redundancy and have no concept of its idiomatic use).